# A statement regarding tangent cones and polyhedricity and variational inequalities (need help with a proof)

Tags: functional-analysis, convex-analysis, variational-analysis, convex-cone

I'm reading this [thesis](https://monarch.qucosa.de/api/qucosa%3A20765/attachment/ATT-0/) on page 182. We work in a Hilbert space $H$, and $y \in H$ solves the variational inequality:
$$y \in K : \langle Ay-f, v-y \rangle \geq 0 \; \forall v \in K$$
for some given closed and convex set $K \subset H$.

Define $\lambda = f-Ay \in H^*$ where $f \in H^*$ is given. We have a quantity

$$\delta\lambda \in (R_K(y) \cap \lambda^\perp)^\circ$$

where $C^\circ$ means the polar cone of $C$ and $\lambda^\perp$  is the nullspace of a functional $\lambda$, and $R_K(y)$ is the radial cone of   $K$ at the point $y \in K$. We have also that

$$\delta y \in T_K(y)\cap \lambda^\perp$$

where $T_K(y)$ is the tangent cone.

The author states that due to the polyhedricity of $K$, which means that
$$\overline{R_K(y)\cap \lambda^\perp} = T_K(y) \cap \lambda^\perp,$$
and because $\delta\lambda = h-A\delta y$, we can deduce that $\delta_y$ solves the variational inequality
$$\delta y \in T_K(y) \cap \lambda^\perp : \langle A\delta y - h, v-\delta y \rangle \geq 0, \; \forall v \in T_K(y) \cap \lambda^\perp.$$

I can't get how $\delta y$ satisfies that inequality using the definitions of the polar cone and usual manipulations. I can only get
$$\langle h-A\delta y, z \rangle = \langle \delta\lambda, z \rangle \leq 0 \;\forall z \in T_K(y)\cap \lambda^\perp.$$
How can I get the correct element in the dual pairing? I don't see how I can choose $z=c(v-\delta y)$  for $c > 0$ and $v \in  T_K(y)\cap \lambda^\perp$ arbitrary. Can someone help with the steps?

Comment: Somehow the relation $\langle A\delta y -h,\delta y\rangle \le0$ has to be used there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The author seems to be a little bit fast at this point: at this point you only get that $\delta\lambda \in (T_K(y) \cap \lambda^\perp)^o$. The next chain of inequalities gives $\langle \delta\lambda, \delta y\rangle = 0$. Then, the VI for the derivative follows.

Comment: I should have read further :D thanks